# Getting value from VAR

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

For the following code

```
var validate = from P in this.DataContext.Persons
                         where P.UserName.Equals(login) && P.Password.Equals(password)
                         select new
                         {
                             P.FirstName,
                             P.LastName,
                             P.EmailAddress
                         };
```

If record exists i want to get the first name and return it. How can i get the firstName from var validate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validate` here is going to be a *set* (`IQueryable<T>`) of data. You may need to use `FirstOrDefault()`, for example:

```
var record = validate.FirstOrDefault();
if(record != null) {
    string firstName = record.FirstName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(validate.FirstOrDefault().FirstName);
```

Otherwise you'll have to loop through the set since that what your query is returning Likely a set of one but it's still a set.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var validate = (from P in this.DataContext.Persons
                where P.UserName.Equals(login) && P.Password.Equals(password)
                select new
                {
                  P.FirstName,
                  P.LastName,
                  P.EmailAddress
                }).FirstOrDefault();

if (validate != null) 
{ 
  var firstName = validate.FirstName;
  ...
}
```